# combining plot3D , plotly and ggplot visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, r-plotly

Can we combine multiple type of 3d visuals.
I want to combine
3d scatterplot using plot3d package
3d scatterplot using plotly package
3d scatterplot using ggplot package

```
library(plotly)

mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

pltly <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
pltly <- pltly %>% add_markers()
pltly <- pltly %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                     zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')))

pltly
x <- sep.l <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- pet.l <- iris$Petal.Length
z <- sep.w <- iris$Sepal.Width

s3d <-scatter3D(x, y, z, clab = c("Sepal", "Width (cm)"))
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(gear)))

#I want to combine all 3.
```

All three can be rendered individually but fails when combined.
Any help/direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi rdb. What do you mean "combine them"? How do you combine a 2d plot and a 3d plot? What is the output that you expect or desire?

Comment: Combine with grid.arrange or subplot in plotly or mfrow

Comment: Ah, so you just mean display them on the same page?

Comment: Correct. Thanks for looking into this. I have tried several options but have been unsuccessful.